# Securing Windows Near Door

Tags: security

I already have a deadbolt keyed lock on my front door, but there is a small vertical window next to it and one above the door that could be broken out and a smaller person could get through or a larger one hoisted to above the door to get in. The door is secure, but I need help with the windows.

Thanks!

Comment: Locks just keep honest people honest. If they want in, they’ll get in...door, window, whatever.

Comment: you can get glass that is hard to break. there's also laminates that can be applied to existing windows. lexan can stop shotgun slugs, and decorative iron grates will stop even the skinniest burgler.